# Background services stop and adb is disconected when net is disconnected in emulator

Tags: android, service, background, image-uploading

I want to create a background service in which it will continuously check for the net connection and if the net connection is available then it will fetch the image path saved in the database and will upload the images.
                 What i want is while uploading image if the net is disconnected due to network issue or any other means the app should stop the upload process and again check for the net connection available or not continuously till it find the connection and start the upload process.
                 Now the issue is when the uploading is  started and if the net is disconnected using F8 in the emulator it disconnect the emulator from the ADB and i ma not able to check whats is happening and when i connect the phone again to net and refresh the adb emulator is connected but background service stops.
Here is the code that i tried

```
public class MyService extends Service{

public static final String TAG = "MyService";
ConnectionDetector cd;
boolean isInternetPresent = false;
boolean uploadingdata = false;
Integer serverResponseCode = 0;
String[] sourceFileUri;
String date;
private static long TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 120;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
private TimerTask Chcknet = new TimerTask(){

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
     date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
         cd  = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
         isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
         Log.d(TAG,"Continously running: "+date);
         Looper.prepare();
         try {
         if(isInternetPresent )
         {
            if(!uploadingdata)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"call fetchdata"+date);

                    fetchdata();

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Already uplaoding data"+date);
            }

         }
         else{
            uploadingdata = false;
            Log.d(TAG,"NO Internet Connection");
         }
         } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         Looper.loop();
}   };

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void onCreate()
{

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/logcat.txt";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-f", filePath, "MyAppTAG:V", "*:S"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(Chcknet,1000L,20*1000L);
    Log.d(TAG,"Fetchdata"+date);
}
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag,int Startid)
{
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void fetchdata() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TestDatabase test_db = new TestDatabase(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = test_db.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select url from test_data where upload_Status='NO'",null);
        cursor.getCount();
        Log.d("TAG","value in the cursor: "+cursor.getCount());
        sourceFileUri = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i=0;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{
            sourceFileUri[i] = cursor.getString(0);
            i++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        Log.d(TAG,"length of the uri string: "+sourceFileUri.length);
        }
        if(sourceFileUri.length>0)
        {
            new doFileUpload().execute(sourceFileUri);
        }
}
class doFileUpload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Integer>
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification.Builder nmBuilder;

    String fileName;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary ;


    File sourceFile;
    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.8:82/UploadToServer.php";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d(TAG,"In doFileUpload"+sourceFileUri);
         nmBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("Uploading Files")
            .setContentText("Uploading in progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Intent intt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
            PendingIntent pdint = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intt, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            nmBuilder.setContentIntent(pdint);
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,nmBuilder.build());
         for(int i=0;i<sourceFileUri.length;i++)
            {
                fileName = sourceFileUri[i]; 
                sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri[i]);


              try {
                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                  uploadingdata = true;
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(urlString);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   boundary = "------------------boundary";
                   String tail = "\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n";
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setDoOutput(true);

                   String metadataPart = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
                              + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n\r\n"
                              + "" + "\r\n";

                   String fileHeader1 = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
                              + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadfile\"; filename=\""
                              + fileName + "\"\r\n"
                              + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                              + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";

                   long fileLength = sourceFile.length() + tail.length();
                          String fileHeader2 = "Content-length: " + fileLength + "\r\n";
                          String fileHeader = fileHeader1 + fileHeader2 + "\r\n";
                          String stringData = metadataPart + fileHeader;

                   long requestLength = stringData.length() + fileLength;
                          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + requestLength);
                          conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) requestLength);
                          conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                          conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                          conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
                          conn.connect();

                   long endTime = new Date().getTime();
                   Log.d("StartTime","starttime: "+startTime);
                   Log.d("EndTime","endTime: "+endTime);
                   long timeoutStatus = (endTime-startTime)/1000;
                   Log.d("TimeOutStatus","timeoutStatus: "+timeoutStatus);

                   if(timeoutStatus>TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)
                   {
                       throw new Exception();
                   }
                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(stringData);

                   int bytesRead, progress = 0;

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                   BufferedInputStream bufInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
                   String temp =null;
                   for(String retval :fileName.split("/")){
                       temp = retval;

                   }

                   while ((bytesRead = bufInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                       // write output
                       dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                       dos.flush();
                       progress += bytesRead;
                       // update progress bar
                       nmBuilder.setProgress(100,(int) ((progress*100)/fileLength),false);
                       nmBuilder.setContentText("Uplaoding "+temp+" in progress");
                       notificationManager.notify(0,nmBuilder.build());

                     }

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                        nmBuilder.setProgress(0, 0,false);
                        nmBuilder.setContentText(temp+" Upload complete");
                        notificationManager.notify(0,nmBuilder.build());
                   }   

                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch(SocketException e){
                  System.out.println("SockeyException "+e);
              }
                  catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
              }catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
              {
                  System.out.println("timeout exsception occured "+conn.getReadTimeout());
              }
              catch(Exception e) 
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e); 
              }

            }
             return serverResponseCode;
  }
}
```

}

So please let me know what is the problem.
     Any help is appreciated.
   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please check yours net connection each time and than proceed accordingly!!

Comment: didn't  got what ur telling i m checking the net connection after every 20 secs using a Timer in the oncreate method

Comment: oh ok...if i will found any feasible answer than i will reply

Comment: ok and there is one more issue in this when try to run this and start the service its starts uploading the image file and in the middle of uploading if i disconnect the net then the emulator is also disconnected form the ADB and if i refresh the adb to reconnect the emulator it show following msg in the logat I/System.out(2871): SockeyException java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) I/System.out(2871): SockeyException java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 82) after 1000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)